# What, other than popcorn, can be made in a popcorn maker?

Tags: equipment, popcorn

What can successfully be made using a popcorn maker, other than the various kinds of popping corn?

I've tried pumpkin seeds and, while they didn't pop, they did become toasted and actually quite nice.

Comment: Is your popcorn maker the constantly stirring type, one to which you add oil?

Comment: I've heard that air poppers can be used for roasting nuts ... but I've never tried myself, so can't confirm it.

Comment: It's an air popper, I think, similar to this http://www.amazon.co.uk/Severin-117803-Popcorn-Maker-White/dp/B00008WV6Z/ref=tag_stp_s2_edpp_url

Answer (score 2):

Many popcorn makers can be used to roast coffee...you will likely destroy it as a popcorn popper over time, however.

Comment: IIRC, only certain forced air models were good at roasting coffee.  http://www.sweetmarias.com/airpop/airpopdesign.php

Answer (score -2):

I think about this aswell, i feel that a popcorn maker and cook many things. i personally feel that many things can be cooked in a popcorn maker. including potatoes, chocolate cake, chicken, chips, and a personal faveroute battered sausages

Comment: Assuming that this post is not a prank, this is the first time I have wished to have two *down*votes per post, I would have liked one for the chocolate cake and one for the battered sausages

Comment: I want to upvote this for its comedy value [but I won't]. I do think you ought to try tomato soup or lamb tikka masala too…;)